# Function components cannot have string refs. We recommend using useRef() instead

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a counter state using useState and useRef. However I'm getting this error

Here's my code

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';


const App = () => {
  const [clicks, setClick] = useState(0)
  const myComponentDiv = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (myComponentDiv && myComponentDiv.current) {
      myComponentDiv.current.addEventListener('click', clickHandler)
      return () => {
        myComponentDiv.current.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler)
      }
    }
  }, [myComponentDiv]);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setClick(clicks + 1)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <div className="my-component" ref="myComponentDiv">
        <h2>My Component {clicks} clicks</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

May i know where i did wrong?

Comment: Change `setClick(clicks + 1)` to `setClick(clicks => clicks + 1)`.

Comment: May i know what's the difference? I mean its like the same isn't?

Comment: The second allows you to have always the last updated state, related to [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in JavaScript. For know I would say use it every time you update a state by touching the sate itself like `setClick(clicks + 1)` .

Comment: So you recommend to use closures to update states like you did in the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
ref="myComponentDiv"
```

should be:

```
ref={myComponentDiv}
```

Comment: The Code now works but it only updates the state to + 1. is there any wrong in the logic of the useEffect?